# "No activity found to handle intent" error

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm beginning to develop and I tried following a [set of tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3) on Youtube. I got really confused after trying to follow tutorial 1.8.

What happens is I launch the application (using the emulator), then it opens the application. It then goes to the splash.xml screen, which is just a background, for five seconds. Then, it's suppose to go back to MainActivity.java screen, which is the main screen. Unfortunately, after showing five seconds of the splash screen, it tells me the application has stopped.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eduardopelaez.minecraftforums"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

splash.xml (which is shown for 5 seconds after opening application):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/minecraft_wallpaperrepeating"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java (which is suppose to come after splash.xml, but this is where it crashes):

```
package com.eduardopelaez.minecraftforums;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle TravisIsAwesome) {
        super.onCreate(TravisIsAwesome);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                    Intent menuIntent = new Intent(
                            "com.eduardopelaez.minecraftforums.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(menuIntent);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        logoTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to Start your MainActivity again.
The Intent code is wrong too, generally it looks like:
    new Intent(this, ActivityToStart.class); //when this, is the current Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent menuIntent = new Intent(
                                 MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(menuIntent);
```

Comment: Great! Now, I want the splash.xml to last five seconds, then go to activity_main.xml. Sorry if this is easy, my head is aching right now.

Comment: You need to have two activities, one for splash screen and one for main Activity. Make splash screen launcher in manifest and then call the second from it as given above.

Answer (score 0):

the goal of an intent is to start an OTHER activity from the existing one. So you should have something like splash activity and in that splash activity you declare your new intent to the mainActivity (2 java files).

BTW even so it seems you are making 2 mistakes :

1. format is incorrect is should be new intent (context, activity_name) and the you did new intent (" "activity_name)
2. your activity com.eduardopelaez.minecraftforums.MainActivity not is com.eduardopelaez.minecraftforums.MAINACTIVITY